# Nextjs 13 Route 404

Tags: javascript, next.js13

I am using Next JS version 13 with app directory configuration, I am designing a product page using dynamic routes but when accessing it is getting 404 error, below image
[image: Error Image]

Can anyone help me, I'm really confused, I spent 16 hours working to find the cause but still can't solve it :(

Comment: what uri are you trying to get?